# Not receiving proper message from fbchat

Tags: python

```
from fbchat import log, Client
from ais import abc

# Subclass fbchat.Client and override required methods
class EchoBot(Client):
def onMessage(self, author_id, message_object, thread_id, thread_type, **kwargs):
    self.markAsDelivered(author_id, thread_id)
    self.markAsRead(author_id)

    log.info("{} from {} in {}".format(message_object, thread_id, thread_type.name))

    # If you're not the author, echo
    if author_id != self.uid:
        abc(message_object) <-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM

client = EchoBot("email", "password")
client.listen()
```

The problem is that message_object instead of being the sent message itself (123123) somehow becomes `<Message (id): '123123', mentions=[] emoji_size=None attachments=[]>` How can i fix this to get the desired result? (123123)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
abc(message_object)
```

with

> abc(message_object.text)